# How to acces a returned value from a Google Maps Geocoder

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, maps

```
geocoder.geocode( { 'address': full_address}, function(results, status) {
    lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
    lng = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
    alert(lat); // works perfectly
});
alert(lat); // doesn't return anything
```

How come the last alert outside the object doesn't return anything? Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: You might want to add some additional text to your `alert` calls that identifies which you are seeing on the screen. The `geocode` call is async, so my guess is that the second call to `alert` actually runs first, followed by the `alert` call within your callback function. Do you see 2 alert dialogs?

Comment: Yes, the first one is blank. And the second one runs first indeed.

Answer (score 1):

Might this be a variable scope issue?  If the variable is local to the object/function, it may not be defined outside that block.  If you declare lat and lng as global before the object code, you may be ok:

```
var lat;
var lng;

geocoder.geocode( { 'address': full_address}, function(results, status) {
lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
lng = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
alert(lat); // works perfectly
});
alert(lat); // doesn't return anything
```